# Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'id<NSFastEnumeration,NSObject>'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, promise, cocoapods

i'm unable to build my project on Xcode 9.3. Build failed. But i'm using below pod files. The issue is happening only Pod file.

```
pod 'PromiseKit/Foundation', '~> 1.5.0'
pod 'PromiseKit-AFNetworking', '~> 0.1.7'
```

Error :

```
PMKPromise *promise = promises[key]; ---> error (Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'id<NSFastEnumeration,NSObject>')
```

My project is working on Xcode 9.2 version. Issue only Xcode 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below pods

```
pod 'PromiseKit/Foundation', '~> 1.7.2'
pod 'PromiseKit-AFNetworking', '~> 0.1.6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your pods to :

```
pod "PromiseKit/Foundation", "~> 6.0.0"  
pod 'PromiseKit-AFNetworking', '~>0.6.0'
```

Comment: [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "PromiseKit/CorePromise":
  In Podfile:
    PromiseKit-AFNetworking (~> 0.6) was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
      PromiseKit/CorePromise (~> 3.0)

    PromiseKit/Foundation (~> 6.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      PromiseKit/CorePromise (= 6.0.0)

Comment: it's same issue